# How to use Math.atan2 to move an object to a specific place

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

Imagine I put an object on the screen at the point

```
        X=6; e Y =60;
```

Now I'm trying to do that:

```
        double radius = Math.atan2(Object.x(), Object.y());
        this.dx2 =Math.cos(radius);
        this.dy2 =Math.sin(radius);
```

From the right side of the screen it will appear random circles.

The hight of the screen is 160, so from 0 to 160 it can appear a circle.

The X of those circles is always the same (the maximum width).

They come from right to left (where the target is).

I'd like all of them to go to this target.

The idea is do that for moving the circles on update method:

```
         x -=(dx2 * spd);  y -=(dy2 * spd);
```

Comment: Do you really know how atan2 works? I will "convert" cartesian coordinates (x,y) to polar coordinates ($\theta$,magnitude). May you post a minimum working example?

Comment: I tried to use Math.toDegrees(x).  I know it is about radius number. I didn't understand the logic for the path  all the circles could do. I saw an example working and it was all about the codes I posted.

Comment: I am very suspicious of using `atan2` to assign a variable called `radius`. It doesn't give you a length, it gives you an angle. (Also, note that you're using `x` as both arguments).

Comment: The double x was just a typo.